# How to bulk insert data with the string of time in mongoid

Tags: mongoid

```
class Topic
  include Mongoid::Document
  #....
  field :public_at, type: DateTime
  #...
end

Topic.collection.insert([{public_at: "2013-10-30 11:45:56"}])
```

`$> Topic.first`

> Hirb Error: undefined method `getlocal' for "2013-10-30 11:45:56":String

Did not convert to Time.

Comment: Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: That's a problem with Hirb not mongoid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are inserting a String where you want a Time
at the Moped driver level for batch (Array of Hashes) insert.
MongoDB supports BSON type UTC datetime, which is mapped to Ruby Time by the Moped driver.
The following test shows what you want with conversion of the String to a Time using Time#parse.
Note that your public_at field is a DateTime as specified at the model level for Topic.
Hope that this helps.

test/unit/topic_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class TopicTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Topic.delete_all
    puts
  end
  test "0. mongoid version" do
    puts "Mongoid::VERSION:#{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped::VERSION:#{Moped::VERSION}"
  end
  test "batch insert" do
    time = Time.parse("2013-10-30 11:45:56")
    Topic.collection.insert([{public_at: time}])
    assert_equal 1, Topic.count
    assert_equal DateTime, Topic.first.public_at.class
    p Topic.first
  end
end
```

$ rake test

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/2] TopicTest#test_0._mongoid_version
Mongoid::VERSION:3.1.5
Moped::VERSION:1.5.1
[2/2] TopicTest#test_batch_insert
#<Topic _id: 528c23e68ce7aa1e667734de, public_at: 2013-10-30 15:45:56 UTC>
Finished tests in 0.051755s, 38.6436 tests/s, 38.6436 assertions/s.
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```